# I have Object array like Object[]. It can hold 3-4 user defined class along with default java primitive. How to handle this in gson?

Tags: java, object, serialization, gson, generic-type-argument

I have Object array like Object[]. It can hold 3-4 user defined class along with default java primitives like long,int etc.. How to handle this in gson? Also for primitives i should use integers as integer itself instead of Double.

PS. Many suggested to have specific datatype array like ClassA[] or int[]. But as per my design it is essential to have as generic Object[]

Class Structure is as follows

There are three user defined classes like Class A, Class B, Class C. And my main class is as follows

```
Class Main
{
   Object [] var=new Object[4];
   var[0]=new ClassA();
   var[1]=new ClassB();
   var[2]=new Long(123);
   var[3]=new String("abc");
}
```

I want to serialize and deserialize above class using gson..

Note: In above example i have assigned 'Variables[]' explicitly but in real time i dont know what Object[] holds. It can hold any one of user defined classes (Class A,B,C) or java primitive

Comment: Posting code is often very helpful to bring across the problem of your question.

Comment: @hotzst I have edited my question with code snipet. Thanks in advance :)